# Finding direction and route from current location to marker direction api

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I am currently working on school project on making a map related application.
I somehow made to getting current location and making marker on searched address.
I however does not understand how to find direction from current location to marker. I know that I have to use direction api but Im lost please help me

this is my code

```
public class MapsActivity2 extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity2";
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 10;
    private static final LatLngBounds LAT_LNG_BOUNDS = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(-40,-168), new LatLng(71, 136));

    private Boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private PlaceAutocompleteAdapter mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private GeoDataClient mGeoDataClient;
    private PlaceInfo mPlace;
    private Marker mMarker;
    private AutoCompleteTextView mSearchText;


    private ImageView mGps, mInfo, mPlacePicker;

    private GeoApiContext mGeoApiContext = null;

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            getDeviceLocation();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            init();

        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        mSearchText = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.input_search);
        mGps = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_gps);
        mInfo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.place_info);
        mPlacePicker = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.place_picker);
        getLocationPermission();

        if (mGeoApiContext == null){
            mGeoApiContext = new GeoApiContext.Builder()
                    .apiKey(getString(R.string.google_maps_key)).build();

        }


    }

    private void init(){
        Log.d(TAG, "init: initialising enter key");

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .build();

        mSearchText.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);

        mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(this, mGoogleApiClient, LAT_LNG_BOUNDS, null);

        mSearchText.setAdapter(mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter);

        mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                        || i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    geoLocate();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        mGps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getDeviceLocation();

            }
        });

        mInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onclick: clicked place info");
                try{
                    if (mMarker.isInfoWindowShown()){
                        mMarker.hideInfoWindow();
                    }else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onclick: place info" + mPlace.toString());
                        mMarker.showInfoWindow();
                    }

                }catch (NullPointerException e){
                    Log.e(TAG, "onClick: NullPointerException" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

        mPlacePicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

                try {
                    startActivityForResult(builder.build(MapsActivity2.this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onClick:GooglePlayServicesRepairableException: "+ e.getMessage());
                } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onClick:GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException: "+ e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });


    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);

                PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResut = Places.GeoDataApi
                        .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, place.getId());
                placeResut.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);

            }
        }
    }

    private void geoLocate(){
        Log.d(TAG, "geolocate: geolocating");
        String searchingString = mSearchText.getText().toString();

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapsActivity2.this);
        List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchingString, 1);
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "geolocate: IOException" + e.getMessage());
        }
        if (list.size() > 0){
            Address address = list.get(0);
            //Toast.makeText(this, address.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.d(TAG, "geolocate: found location 123123 "+ address.toString());

            moveCamera(new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude()),DEFAULT_ZOOM, address.getAddressLine(0));
        }
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */

    private void getDeviceLocation(){
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try{
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted){
                final Task Location = mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation();
                Location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Found Location");
                            android.location.Location currentLocation = (android.location.Location) task.getResult();



                            moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(),currentLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM , "my location");



                        }else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Current Location");
                            //Toast.makeText(MapsActivity2.this, "Unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: Security exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom, PlaceInfo placeInfo){
        Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: moving to : " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));

        mMap.clear();

        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter(MapsActivity2.this));

        if (placeInfo != null){
            try{
                String snippet = "Address: " + placeInfo.getAddress() + "\n" +
                        "Phone Number: " + placeInfo.getPhoneNumber() + "\n" +
                        "Website: " + placeInfo.getWebsiteUri() + "\n" +
                        "Rating: " + placeInfo.getRating() + "\n";

                MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .title(placeInfo.getName())
                        .snippet(snippet);
                mMarker = mMap.addMarker(options);


            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                Log.e(TAG, "NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }else {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        }




    }


    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom, String title){
        Log.d(TAG, "moveCamera: moving to : " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " + latLng.longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));

        if (!title.equals("my location")){
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(title);
            mMap.addMarker(options);

        }


    }



    private void getLocationPermission(){
        String [] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                mLocationPermissionGranted = true;

            }else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
        else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
        switch (requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                        if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener= new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            final AutocompletePrediction item = mPlaceAutocompleteAdapter.getItem(i);
            final String placeID = item.getPlaceId();

            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResut = Places.GeoDataApi
                    .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeID);
            placeResut.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
        }
    };



    private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
            if(!places.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                Log.d(TAG, "onResult: place query not successful: "+ places.getStatus().toString());
                places.release();//prevent memory leak
                return;
            }
            final Place place = places.get(0);
            try {


            mPlace = new PlaceInfo();
            mPlace.setName(place.getName().toString());
            mPlace.setAddress(place.getAddress().toString());
            //mPlace.setAttribution(place.getAttributions().toString());
            mPlace.setId(place.getId());
            mPlace.setLatlng(place.getLatLng());
            mPlace.setRating(place.getRating());
            mPlace.setPhoneNumber(place.getPhoneNumber().toString());
            mPlace.setWebsiteUri(place.getWebsiteUri());

            Log.d(TAG, "OnResult: place" + mPlace.toString());

            }catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResult: NullPointerException" + e.getMessage());
            }
            moveCamera(new LatLng(place.getViewport().getCenter().latitude, place.getViewport().getCenter().longitude), DEFAULT_ZOOM, mPlace);

            places.release();


        }
    };
}
```

Comment: but how do i find location from my current location and to where marker is?

Comment: see the answer (and the linked tutorial) on the other post... while your code has the fundamental issue, that you pass lat/lng as `int` values; which most likely should be of type `double`.... `new LatLng(-34, 151)` probably should be `new LatLng(-34.0, 151.0)`.

Comment: ummm that was just for example, I have read that answer and tutorial but I am not sure of sending original latlng and destination latlng to find the location, which for original latlng it will be my current location and destination will be the marker i click will this make sense? sorry and thanks for reply